# ASP MVC 4 Mapping one to one relationship code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I am new to ASP MVC and am working on a project with complex related data model. so while working on the relationships i looked online and got the following example on the Blog of asps.net :

```
namespace CodeFirst.Associations.OneToOneFK
{
    public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }        
        public int BillingAddressId { get; set; }
        public int DeliveryAddressId { get; set; }       

        public Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
        public Address DeliveryAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }   
    }
}
```

So my doubt is do we really need both the int BillingAddressID as well as Address BillingAddress?
Also, how do we associate an address to a user if we don't use AddressID.

Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int BillingAddressID` is called a foreign key property.

`BillingAddress` is called a navigation property (in this case a reference navigation property).

Foreign key properties aren't required to define a relationship, but they do simplify certain coding patterns. The general recommendation is to use both navigation properties and foreign key properties.

See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/03/16/foreign-keys-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) for more information about why FK associations were introduced.